# Making a private Route for settings of a user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**Error**
Uncaught Error: A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your  in a .

**Private Router**

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => {
        if(auth.user){
          return children;
        }
        return <Navigate to='/login' />
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />

          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />

          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Signup />} />

          <Route exact path="/settings" element={<PrivateRoute><Settings /></PrivateRoute>} />

          <Route element={<Page404 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

I was trying to Privating the route for settings , but got error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace your settings route by this :

```
<Route exact path="/settings" component={PrivateRoute}><Settings /></Route>
```